# Fast laptop that can run Linux, 8-16 cores, 16-23 GiB RAM, => 2TB storage, Swedish keyboard, available in EU?

Tags: laptop, linux

I want a fast, portable Linux system for development purposes; I need to be able to compile in parallel, preferably 16 cores, a Swedish keyboard, and 2-3 TB storage; I liked the following.

https://slimbook.es/en/store/slimbook-executive/executive-1-comprar

https://www.pcw.fr/ (but they don't seem to come with a Swedish keyboard)

Do you think I have many alternatives, or should I choose the slim book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I would reccomend the Framework laptop, although it's not availible in Sweden (yet) or with Swedish keyboard layout (yet) although it is availible with multiple QWERTY layouts and with a clear layout. It has CPUs with up to 14 cores I think (on Intel 12th gen), has 2 RAM slots (each of which supporting 4-32GB RAM) and one SSD slot (which officially supports up to 4TB but I think you can technically do 8TB too). The ports are customizable and installing Linux is pretty easy. I use mine for developing too (although mine is 11th gen Intel) and I like it, although I also had to use keyboard stickers because when we ordered it they didn't have a Belgian keyboard layout yet (and that is the one I'm used to)